# Delete old versions in Sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, client-side-scripting

I am using SharePoint online and in that I have few document libraries. Version history is enabled and tracked from 2016. I want to retain only the versions of 2018, 2019 and delete all the previous year versions.

Is there a way to achieve this using JavaScript client object model ? ( I am not looking for PowerShell way ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Iterate over the items in listItem.Versions then delete them.

This is CSOM but it should hopefully give you a bit of an idea of what I mean (JSOM is basically the same in this case):

```
ctx2.Load(spDocument.ListItem.File.Versions);
ctx2.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(var version in spDocument.ListItem.Versions){
   // do delete logic here
}
spDocument.ListItem.Update();
ctx2.ExecuteQuery();
```